# SQL Server: Check Date of Previous Record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table that is storing transactions on a database whenever someone checks out and checks in a card. I am trying to come up with a view to show all card transactions where a person did not check-in a card within 7 days of a checkout. My table looks like below:

```
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| Card_Number |   Status    | Transaction_Date |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
|      123456 | Checked In  | 7/8/2018         |
|      123456 | Checked Out | 7/1/2018         |
|      234567 | Checked In  | 7/8/2018         |
|      234567 | Checked Out | 7/1/2018         |
|      456789 | Checked In  | 7/5/2018         |
|      456789 | Checked Out | 7/1/2018         |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
```

In the example I would want the records with card numbers 123456 and 234567 but for some reason I can't figure out a good way to make this work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into SQL Servers LEAD / LAG functions? These allow easy access to the previous or next rows.

Example:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE ( [card_number] VARCHAR(15), [status] VARCHAR(15), [transaction_date] DATETIME );

INSERT INTO @data (
            [card_number], [status], [transaction_date]
        ) VALUES
        ( '123456', 'Checked In', '07/08/2018' )
        , ( '123456', 'Checked Out', '07/01/2018' )
        , ( '234567', 'Checked In', '07/08/2018' )
        , ( '234567', 'Checked Out', '07/01/2018' )
        , ( '456789', 'Checked In', '07/05/2018' )
        , ( '456789', 'Checked Out', '07/01/2018' );

        SELECT
            [card_number]
            , [status]
            , CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), [transaction_date], 101 ) AS [txn_date]
            , CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), LAG( [transaction_date], 1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY [card_number], [transaction_date] ), 101 ) AS [prev_txn_date]
            , CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), LEAD( [transaction_date], 1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY [card_number], [transaction_date] ), 101 ) AS [next_txn_date]
        FROM @data 
        WHERE
            [card_number] = '123456'
        ORDER BY 
            [card_number], [transaction_date];
```

Returns:

```
+-------------+-------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| card_number |   status    |  txn_date  | prev_txn_date | next_txn_date |
+-------------+-------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
|      123456 | Checked Out | 07/01/2018 | NULL          | 07/08/2018    |
|      123456 | Checked In  | 07/08/2018 | 07/01/2018    | NULL          |
+-------------+-------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for but I don't want to have a where statement using card number. Is it possible to use lag or lead in the where statement so that I can somehow compare the dates in a calculation?

Comment: Never mind I was able to make this work and suite my needs. Thank you Critical Error for your help.

Comment: To answer your question, yes. Which you’ve already determined, lol. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` is the first thing that comes to mind:

```
select t.*
from t
where status = 'Checked Out' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.card_number = t.card_number and
                        t2.status = 'Checked In' and
                        t2.transaction_date >= t.transaction_date and
                        t2.transaction_date < dateadd(day, 7, t.transaction_date)
                 );
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, could you explain a bit more about using 'Not Exists'? I've tried your example and I am getting nothing back when I use 'Not Exists'. If I use 'Exists' instead I get rows back.

Comment: @Jestes . . . Your question is "I am trying to come up with a view to show all card transactions where a person did not check-in a card within 7 days of a checkout."  That suggests `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from T t
where status = 'out' and not exists (
    select 1 from T t2
    where t2.card = t.card
        and t2.status = 'in'
        and t.dt between t2.dt and dateadd(day, 6, t.dt)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I did this right but this is what I attempted. Hope it helps !

```
select card_number, transaction_date, sta
from
(
select t1.card_number, t1.transaction_date, t1.sta, datediff(DAY, t1.transaction_date, t2.transaction_date) as diff
from trans t1
join trans t2
on t1.card_number = t2.card_number
) result
where diff=7 and sta = 'Checked Out'
```